# Pandas is not empty but gets max() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, error-handling, max

This is toy data and it works fine to get the max index of `True` from each list of `Pandas` column `allmz` into  `lastprec`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.Series([1,1,1,3,3]),'allmz':([[True,True,True],[True,False,True],[False,True,False],[True,True,False],[True,False,False]]),'allint':([[11,31,31],[21,41,51],[41,51,51],[11,31,51],[1,51,11]])})

df['lastprec'] = df['allmz'].apply(lambda aa: max([i for i, x in enumerate(aa) if x]))
print df

>>>OUT
         allint                 allmz  time  lastprec
0  [11, 31, 31]    [True, True, True]     1         2
1  [21, 41, 51]   [True, False, True]     1         2
2  [41, 51, 51]  [False, True, False]     1         1
3  [11, 31, 51]   [True, True, False]     3         1
4   [1, 51, 11]  [True, False, False]     3         0
```

However, in my real data, I got `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`. Only thing that is different is I open that `DataFrame` from Excel (but the toy data is not imported) by `ref_df = pd.read_excel(ref_file, sheetname=ref_worksheet)`. Can this be a reason why I get this error? Or there is something else? I check the real data `allmz`, it is not empty and the data type is `list`. What can I fix to get the max index of the real data?

Comment: What does `df.allmz.str.len().eq(0).any()` print?

Comment: it prints `False`

Comment: In that case, data like `[False, False, False]` is causing your problem.

Comment: I am sure it does not have all False. I even copy to take a look in Excel. May you suggest the code to check where is the line of problem? Like `np.where(df.allmz.str.len().eq(0))`?

Comment: `df.allmz.apply(all).all()` What does that print?

Comment: Also print `False`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant `df.allmz.apply(any).all()`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I found that one blank line. (The last one returns `False` btw)

Comment: Looks like you _DO_ have `[False, False, False]`.

Comment: yeah very sorry. fixing them now. thanks so much.

Comment: So, what was the point of the question? They are not supposed to be in your data in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

If not empty lists not all False lists and lenfth of lists is always same, you can use `numpy` for improving performance:

```
df['lastprec'] = 2 - np.array(df['allmz'].values.tolist())[:,::-1].argmax(axis=1)
print (df)

         allint                  allmz  time  lastprec
0  [11, 31, 31]  [False, False, False]     1         2
1  [21, 41, 51]    [True, False, True]     1         2
2  [41, 51, 51]   [False, True, False]     1         1
3  [11, 31, 51]    [True, True, False]     3         1
4   [1, 51, 11]   [True, False, False]     3         0
```

Comment: I am sure that the data does not have `empty` list

Comment: OK, one question - length of lists is same?

Comment: Yes, they are all `3`